# Find and replace string in a specific column with opposite value, one row at a time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm certain the title didn't make any sense, so I apologize.

I have a column where there is one of two possible strings in each cell. The cell either contains "From" or "To". I need a macro that will replace all of the "From" cells with "To" and all of the "To" cells with "From".

The values are currently placed in Column E starting at E2 and can vary in length but most likely less than E50.

I've tried the code below but it isn't working at all:

```
Dim fromToReplace As String 
fromToReplace = Sheets("Template_Test").Range("E100").End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 2 To fromToReplace
        If Cells(i, 5) = "From" Then
            Replace What:="From", Replacement:="To", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
            Else
                Replace What:="To", Replacement:="From", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
        End If
```

Edit Update:

I've now also tried the following -

```
For i = 2 To fromToReplace
    If ActiveCell.Value = "From" Then
         ActiveCell.Value = "To"
         Else ActiveCell.Value = "From"
    EndIf
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Your Method:

You were missing your loop statement (`Next i`). Also, you do not need to use `Replace` since you have already validated the value in your cell with the `If` statement.

If your value is `From` you can just change it to `To` directly *(& vice versa)*

Also, it is **good practice** to **qualify** your use of the `Cells` object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub To_From()

Dim ws As Worksheet, i as Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template_Test")

For i = 2 To ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Cells(i, 5) = "From" Then
        ws.Cells(i, 5) = "To"
    ElseIF ws.Cells(i, 5) = "To" Then
        ws.Cells(i, 5) = "From"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

### A More Efficient Method:

Avoid doing this row by row by storing one of your values with a temporary value (Change `From` to `FromTemp`) to avoid interference with your other swap.

I'm assuming this interference is the only reason you stated this had to be *row by row* in the first place.
 The larger your data set gets, the more appealing this option will become when considering speed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub To_From()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template_Test")

Dim ReplaceRange As Range
Set ReplaceRange = ws.Range("E1:E" & ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

ReplaceRange.Replace "From", "FromTemp", xlWhole
ReplaceRange.Replace "To", "From", xlWhole
ReplaceRange.Replace "FromTemp", "To", xlWhole

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use evaluate:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Template_Test").Range("E2", Sheets("Template_Test").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
rng.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address(1, 1) & "=""To"",""From"",""To"")")
```

Or you can loop and array:

```
Dim rng
rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E2", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
    If rng(i, 1) = "To" Then
        rng(i, 1) = "From"
    Else
        rng(i, 1) = "To"
    End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.Range("E2", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value = rng
```

As far as time to run the codes.  Both these averaged `0.016 seconds` for 10,000 rows

@udearboy sorry to say with yours on 10,000 rows took `0.211` seconds.  Not enough to worry about, but just had to rub it in. :)

Comment: Are you using the `Timer` function to test run time? I just use `Now` time stamps since seconds has been a good enough indicator for me. Just wondering how you are getting into milliseconds so I can find, and validate, a solution that averages at `.015` seconds ;)

Comment: Yes I am using `t = timer` and then at the end `debug.Print timer - t`